# How to determine if a TWAIN Scanner is ADF/Flatbed, or Both

Tags: c++, twain, leadtools-sdk

What is the best way to figure out if the current selected scanner is ADF/Flatbed, or Both using Leadtools SDK 20?
I know I can use `L_TwainGetCapability()` and `L_TwainSetCapability()` with `CAP_FEEDERENABLED` to enable/disable the feeder if it is there, but how can I determine if it has feeder (maybe it is a flatbed only) or has a flatbed (maybe it is ADF only) or has both?

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 0):

I have not used LeadTools, but the check for a flatbed is redundant if the device does not have a feeder.  It either has a feeder, or it doesn't have a feeder.

Remember that a TWAIN device could be a digital camera, and not a scanner -- thus a "flatbed" doesn't make sense.

The current way that I check is to simply see if `CAP_FEEDERENABLED` is supported is the following:

1. Check if **CAP_FEEDERENABLED** is supported.  If not supported, then there is no feeder and you're done.
2. If **CAP_FEEDERENABLED** is supported, save the current setting of **CAP_FEEDERENABLED**.
3. See if setting **CAP_FEEDERENABLED** to TRUE is successful and save the results.
4. Reset **CAP_FEEDERENABLED** with the value saved in step 2.
5. The results saved in step 3 is the determining factor.

Unfortunately, this is the roundabout way I've done this, but it should work.  This is basically described in the TWAIN Specification for CAP_FEEDERENABLED (the version of the specification I use is 2.4).

Comment: Checking for flatbed is NOT redundant because there exists scanners that have ADF but no flatbed. For example [Fujitsu fi-7300](https://scanners.us.fujitsu.com/for-small-business/desktop/fi-7300nx). Also you mentioned `Check if CAP_FEEDERENABLED is supported`. How do you do that?

Comment: Like I mentioned, it either has a feeder, or it doesn't have a feeder.  There is no standard TWAIN capability to check for "flatbed only".  Second, doesn't LeadTools have an API that detects whether a capability is supported? (My [API](https://github.com/dynarithmic/twain_library) has such a function).